# Query the database using a non-id column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have what I think is a non standard model strcture (i know that it is bad, but its neccessary). Given the following migration :

> ```
> create_table :MODELS, :primary_key => :MOD_ID do |t|
>   t.integer :MOD_ID
>   t.integer :MOD_MFA_ID
>   t.integer :MOD_CDS_ID
>   t.integer :MOD_PCON_START
>   t.integer :MOD_PCON_END
>   t.integer :MOD_PC
>   t.integer :MOD_CV
>   t.integer :MOD_AXL
>   t.binary :MOD_PC_CTM
>   t.binary :MOD_CV_CTM
>
>   t.timestamps
> ```

The `MOD_MFA_ID` corresponds to an association to another table/model (`manufacturers`). I would like to retrieve models based on the manufacturer's brand column.

```
  def getmanufacturer 
    @manufacturer = Manufacturers.find(params[:manufacturer])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @manufacturer }
    end
  end
```

I can't figure out how to modify my controller and routing to handle this use case. I'd like to query the app using this kind or URL : `/models?manufacturer=audi&&model=a6`

Answer (score 3):

So saying you want a URL like:

/manufacture/audi/model/a6

in your routes file do:

```
resources manufactures do
  resources models
end
```

For the models you would want to switch your primary key

Manufacturer model:

```
set_primary_key :manufacturer_name #what ever you want used instead of ID
```

Do the same thing for your MODEL model

```
set_primary_key :MOD_Name
```

Then in your controller you can do:

```
Manufacturer.find(params[:manufaturer_id]).models.find(params[:id])
```

If you don't want to switch the primary keys, you can also do find_by:

```
Manufacturer.find_by_manufacturer_name("Audi").models.find_by_model_name("a6")
```

Comment: that's good, but on first step I in model set_primary_key "MFA_ID", but in controller i wanna find not by MFA_ID, but for MOD_Name ???  edit: sorry) i'm realy stupid)) it's no good to learn for 18/7

Comment: You can use the find_by methods.  So try .find_by_mod_name("a6")

Comment: I meen url like /audi/a6/ if it could be?

Comment: also, in finb_by give array or one entry?

Comment: you can pass the same options to find_by that you pass to find

Comment: To get the route you want, you should use Dynamic Segments: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html (section 3.2)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a migration and are creating a new database, then you should make a standard db.  I understand if you are connecting to a database that you were not able to design.  I'd also use lowercase for the field names.

If you want MFA_BRAND to be the primary key, then you can set the primary key in your class.  Suppose you want MFA_ID to be the primary key, then you would add this to your class as:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "MFA_ID"
end
```

This will change the find and to_param methods to use your primary key field.

However, assuming you don't want to change the primary key, but sometimes want to search by MFA_BRAND, then you will want to pass the MFA_BRAND value as a CGI parameter.  First set teh routes as

```
resources :models do
  collection do
    get :getmanufacturer
  end
end
```

When you need the path helper call it this way:

```
getmanufacturer_models_path(:manufacturer => "Acme")
```

the URL will be

```
/models/getmanufacturer?manufacturer=Acme
```

Comment: He already stated it was necessary to have a non standard DB.  Often times a DB is shared among multiple applications.  The question was how to deal with the limitation.

Comment: I did give him a solution to deal with the non-standard db.  I saw that he was using a migration, which makes me think he has some latitude to control *his* database and translate.  However, if he truely doesn't, I still gave him a solution to deal with it.